# i want to see results of all the 3 if sentence

Tags: javascript, if-statement

now i got a problem of javascript if sentence
i want to get a result of all the 3 if sentence(each if sentence's value is different)

i have 3 input box(type="text") and one textarea(for result) in html file : email, date, SSN. and i have to use regExp for matching each value. i've done...
and now i have to show matching result in textarea but i can see just one result like...

```
    if (rgEx1.test(document.getElementById("email").value)) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "e-mail matched";
    }
    if (rgEx2.test(document.getElementById("date").value)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "date matched";
    }
    if (rgEx3.test(document.getElementById("ssn").value)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "SSN matched";
    }
```

with this sentence i can see only ssn matched but i want to see each if sentences' result then what should i do????

Comment: Use your code, just change `innerHTML =` to  `innerHTML +=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable and populate it according to the `if` statements:

```js
function validate() {
  var message = '';

  if (rgEx1.test(document.getElementById('email').value)) {
    message += 'e-mail matched<br>';
  }
  if (rgEx2.test(document.getElementById('date').value)) {
    message += 'date matched<br>';
  }
  if (rgEx3.test(document.getElementById('ssn').value)) {
    message += "SSN matched";
  }

  // set the innerHTML here
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
}

var rgEx1 = {
  test: function(value) {
    return value;
  }
};

var rgEx2 = {
  test: function(value) {
    return value;
  }
};

var rgEx3 = {
  test: function(value) {
    return value;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" />
<input type="date" id="date" />
<input type="text" id="ssn" />

<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Validate Fields">

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable that contains the whole message, then add to the variable whenever a if-statement is true.

```
var result = "";
if (rgEx1.test(document.getElementById("email").value)) {
    result += "e-mail matched";
}
if (rgEx2.test(document.getElementById("date").value)) {
    result += "date matched";
}
if (rgEx3.test(document.getElementById("ssn").value)) {
    result += "SSN matched";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

Of course, you'll want to have some linebreaks or some formatting to it as well or it will look like `e-mail matcheddate matchedSSN matched`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code, just change `innerHTML =` to  `innerHTML +=` , i.e.:

```
 if (rgEx1.test(document.getElementById("email").value)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "e-mail matched<br>";
    }
    if (rgEx2.test(document.getElementById("date").value)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "date matched<br>";
    }
    if (rgEx3.test(document.getElementById("ssn").value)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "SSN matched";
    }
```